# RESTFul Client in Jersey is generating a new shiro (for authentication) session each time

Tags: rest, jackson, shiro, rest-client, jersey-client

I have a rest api that has a login resource for authentication using shiro.
When calling the login from postMan client for example then trying to perform an action, I monitor the shiro session on rest server side and it's always the same.

In addition I have a java client that uses Jersey for creating HTTP requests, but when running it I noticed that each call has a different shiro session!

Creating the client once when doing login:

```
            Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
            baseTarget = client.target(baseUrl);
```

Then in each call I have something like:

```
        Invocation.Builder builder;
        builder = baseTarget.path(apiPath + "blabla")
            .queryParam("bla", bla)
            .
            .
            .
            .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    Response response = builder.post(Entity.json(null));
```

How can I assure having the same session in each call?!

Comment: The sessions are maintained with the use of cookies. Im not sure 100% sure, but I would assume that if the session is maintained on Postman, then Postman sends the cookies automatically to the server. The Jersey client doesn't, by default.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to send include the associated session cookie (by default `JSESSIONID`).